# Laravel Api and Web Authentication At Same Time

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, api, laravel-7

i'm building cross-platform app so i have website and mobile app. also I've Authentication part for both website and app.

and i'm using Laravel As backend. For auth i found something called "Auth Guards" and there are two default Auth guard in Laravel, one for web and other for API.

But i'm a bit confused cause i found that you can't use both Auth Guards at the same time.

So, is there any way to build authentication system based in one Database Table For Website an Mobile.

**NOTE** i need any solution except Firebase Auth

Auth.php

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
```

Comment: these guards both use the same user information (same model and database table)... they just authenticate the request in a different way (one uses the session and one uses a request token) but both use the same exact users (if you haven't changed the user provider in the configuration for each)

Comment: i know but in Auth.php you can only choose one, and if you choose one the the other wouldn't work

Comment: in `Auth.php` ? ... what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: i'm using Laravel 7

Comment: so what `Auth.php` file are you referring to?  when you assign the `auth` middleware you can actually pass it as many guards as you want btw and it will loop through them (middleware parameters)  though not sure if that is what you need

Comment: i update the question... take a look
you can just select one auth guard "web" or "api"
you can't select both guards
For Example: I build api auth using jwt and it's works perfectly but this is when i changed the default auth guard from web to api. and when i do that the web auth stop working. Also if i change the auth guard back to "web" the api auth stop working
So, the trick is making both auth and api guard working at the same time

Comment: that is just the "default", you can use any guards you want ... that is just what is used as a 'default' when you don't specify a guard .. that configuration variable actually changes at run time if you attempt to get the user from other guards ... the main issue with using something like `web` and `api` is that web requires sessions and api does not, so those routes will need session support, which you may not want because of the api

Answer (score 0):

a good solution could be laravel oficial pakage laravel/passport that offer you oauth2 so you can implement it on android/os easly.

Comment: Does that (Laravel Passport) conflict with laravel default web Auth?
Or rather, can i use it with Laravel web authentication ?

Comment: it doesn't follow the doc on: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport

Comment: You can use api guard for mobile and web guard for website.